# php regular expression to convert string followed by number into multiple strings each followed by one of the digits

Tags: php, regex

how to i replace

```
Apple 123456
```

to

```
Apple 1|Apple 2|Apple 3|Apple 4|Apple 5|Apple 6
```

by php pcre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified version of Bogdan's regex using negative lookahead.

Replace number with `"number|Apple "` unless it is the last character in the string.

```
<?
$string = "Apple 123456";
echo preg_replace('/([0-9])(?!$)/', '$1|Apple ', $string);
?>
```

Ouput: `Apple 1|Apple 2|Apple 3|Apple 4|Apple 5|Apple 6`

Answer (score 1):

With this one you get partially what you want:

```
<?php
    echo preg_replace('/([0-9])/', 'Apple $1|', 'Apple 123456');
```

That results in: `Apple Apple 1|Apple 2|Apple 3|Apple 4|Apple 5|Apple 6|`

For removing the first "Apple" you could `str_replace()` or `explode()` the initial string, resulting something like

```
<?php
    $string = 'Apple 123456';
    $string = str_replace("Apple", "", $string);
    echo preg_replace('/([0-9])/', 'Apple $1|', $string);
```

The result here is `Apple 1|Apple 2|Apple 3|Apple 4|Apple 5|Apple 6|`.
You can remove the last pipe by using `substr($result, 0, -1)`.

The final code will look like this:

```
<?php
    $string = 'Apple 123456';
    $string = str_replace("Apple", "", $string);
    $regex = preg_replace('/([0-9])/', 'Apple $1|', $string);
    echo substr($regex, 0, -1);
```