# foreach in regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php regular expression help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263825/php-regular-expression-help)

hi, 
i want to replace

```
i like apple
apple is good
orange is also nice
my mom likes banana
apple 123 4
the pear is soo sweat
my dad loves pear
```

to

```
i like apple
apple is good
orange is also nice
my mom likes banana
apple 1
apple 2
apple 3
apple 4
the pear is soo sweat
my dad loves pear
```

by preg_replace?

Comment: The line you are looking after is `apple [\d\s]+`?

Comment: Can you precise the pattern your looking for ? Can it be more than 1234 ? Is the space correct ? Is it always starting by a 1 ?

Comment: duplicate as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263825/php-regular-expression-help

Comment: What is the difference to your previous question?

Comment: True Soft: yes , i am looking for apple [\d\s], but how to i replace it as above?
Kaaviar: the space are correct , it is not always starting by a 1 but it is always numberic
possible duplicate: this is not the same question because in this question, i have to identify the line i have to replace. when i use the previous question, it replaces all number characters in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
function replace($matches)
{
        return preg_replace("/\s*(\d)\s*/", "$matches[1] $1\n", $matches[2]);
}
$s = "i like apple
apple is good
orange is also nice
my mom likes banana
apple 123 4
the pear is soo sweat
my dad loves pear";
echo "Before::......\n\n$s\n\nAfter::......\n\n";
echo preg_replace_callback('/^(apple) ([\d ]+)\n/m', 'replace', $s);
echo "\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
Before::......

i like apple
apple is good
orange is also nice
my mom likes banana
apple 123 4
the pear is soo sweat
my dad loves pear

After::......

i like apple
apple is good
orange is also nice
my mom likes banana
apple 1
apple 2
apple 3
apple 4
the pear is soo sweat
my dad loves pear
```

Comment: It works!!! I have tried so long time!! thank you so much!!